# Angular 6 - ng-dirty and ng-invalid not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying out some form validation and seeing strange behaviour from the classes that are applied to a form control.

`ng-dirty` is not being applied when I change input value from 'Rob' to 'Ro' but it does get applied when I change the value further to 'R'.

`ng-invalid` does not get applied when I clear out form field and required attribute is present. If I blur out though, the class gets applied.

Link to the code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-classes

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works with no error when the template reference variable `username` is used **after** its definition in the DOM. According to my tests, it can be used inside or outside of the `form` tag, as long as it is after the input element declaration.

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-classes-7ljkut) for a demo.

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" ngForm>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" #userName required class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="userModel.name">
  </div>
</form>
{{userName.className}}  <<-- Works when positioned after userName definition in the DOM
```

Comment: So to conclude Template Reference variable should be used after it is defined not before that

Comment: @Vikas - It is the first time I see this but maybe I had never tried to use a template reference variable before its declaration in the DOM. I also haven't found anything in the documentation about that scope limitation.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: it is not really a scope limitation but rather an influence on the timing when evaluating the values in the template.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan. I didn't know that using it before the temp ref variable affects how it works. I will check on the repo if any similar issue has been raised to try understand more.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I don't fully understand the reasons behind this, but you're getting "ExpressionChangedAfterItWasChecked" errors on the `userName.className` that you're trying to display. It seems to check `userName.className` first, then do the checks on form status based on the events that update it so it's always a step behind. You can synchronize these values by doing an additional change detection ref cycle.

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component and run `detectChanges()` after the view has been checked.

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  topics = ['Angular', 'React', 'Vue'];
  userModel = new User('Rob', 'rob@test.com', 5556665566, 'Angular', 'morning', true);

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: But why does it happen though? That is not the expected behaviour right? I tried this way back in Angular 2 and was working fine. I check the official doc example and works fine as well - https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyykrkdkgryv

Comment: this is correct solution. async event (input field change) runs change detection and then template expression evaluates based on that changed value (but it doesn't trigger new change detection cycle) thus always staying one step behind. That's why triggering it manually makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

what happens is that you're always one change detection step behind (with interpolating classnames) because you're changing the model which in turn changes the value of input field and then you're copying that input field value (through template variable) to other place.

try this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-classes-q97pah?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

here you listen for `ngModelChange` and once it happens, in next tick (`setTimeout`) you show classname values.